# Request mongo in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, readdir

I have put all my files in mongo and I would like to delete all unreferenced files.

To do that, I need to check all my folders and subfolders, get all my files and do a find({"name": fileName}) and if there is no document, I delete my local file.

I would like to know if there is a better way to do it (with or without promise).

First I was doing a list with all my files and check on this list but this is too big. Now, I do the find operation during the readdir.

I don't know well mongo(ose) and maybe there is a lost cost (cpu / mem / ...) to do it

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would say that querying mongo for each `name` is the right approach. Just ensure that your table has an index on the `name` field.

Comment: for now, I got a FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I can't finish my requests :

I have used heapdump and there is too much bson object in memory ... about 4 Go of RAM overflowed....

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed